# PDF UPLOAD ON SELENIUM IDE WEB DRIVER

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I'm creating a test suite to automate some parts of data input on my web application. I have a page where I can click on the button to upload a document to the application.
It looks something like this:

[image]

Can only upload a PDF file.
I set it to `XPath xpath=//input[@id='inputGroupFile03']`
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905237/selenium-ide-web-driver-chrome